# How can I convert a dictionary with a tuple (x, y) key to a matrix or list of lists

Tags: python

I would like to convert a dictionary to a matrix, but where this is different than other questions I've seen is that the dictionary has a tuple of x and y coordinates as the key.  I appreciate your help with this.  I'm using a new python package that requires lists, but all of my data is in dictionaries.

```
test_dict = {
 (0, 0): 11,
 (0, 1): 13,
 (0, 2): 33,
 (1, 0): 24,
 (1, 1): 20,
 (1, 2): 4
}
```

To

```
[[11, 13, 33], [24, 20, 4]]

i.e.

test_list = [[11, 13, 33],
             [24, 20, 4]]
test_list
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have an idea for an approach?

Comment: I've accessed the dict.keys(), dict.items(), and dict.values().  I understand how to iterating over a dictionary with one key, rather than a tuple of keys.  I'm trying to think of a way to expand that: `test_list = [[key]+value for key,value in dct.items()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def dict_to_matrix(the_dict: dict) -> list:
    # Number of rows and columns in the matrix
    nrows = max(key[0] for key in the_dict) + 1
    ncols = max(key[1] for key in the_dict) + 1

    # Initialize the matrix (can use `numpy.empty` here)
    the_matrix = [[None]*ncols for _ in range(nrows)]

    # Fill the matrix
    for (i, j), the_matrix[i][j] in the_dict.items():
        ...

    # Could also do this,
    # but the loop above is more fun, IMO
    # for (i, j), value in the_dict.items():
    #    the_matrix[i][j] = value

    return the_matrix

test_dict = {
 (0, 0): 11,
 (0, 1): 13,
 (0, 2): 33,
 (1, 0): 24,
 (1, 1): 20,
 (1, 2): 4
}

print(dict_to_matrix(test_dict))
```

Example run:

```
~/test $ python test.py 
[[11, 13, 33], [24, 20, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the compact version:

```
[[item for (key, item) in test_dict.items() if k1 == key[0]] for k1 in set(t1 for (t1, t2) in test_dict)]

[[11, 13, 33], [24, 20, 4]]
```

Longer format:

```
tuple_firsts = set(t1 for (t1, t2) in test_dict)
result = []
for k1 in tuple_firsts:
    sub_result = []
    for key, item in test_dict.items():
        if key[0] == k1:
            sub_result.append(item)
    result.append(sub_result)      
result

[[11, 13, 33], [24, 20, 4]]
```

Comment: What if the dictionary is in a different order, but the mapping of tuples to values is the same? This will produce an incorrect result.

Comment: The question appears to imply it's already ordered, however `sorted(test_dict.items())` can be substituted if required.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of defaultdict, the algorithm has O(n) time complexity.
As specified in the comments, you need to sort the dictionary on key. You can do this with [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
>>> new_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> ordered_test_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(test_dict.items()))
>>> for key, val in ordered_test_dict.items():
...    new_dict[key[0]].append(val)
>>> list(new_dict.values())
[[11, 13, 33], [24, 20, 4]]
```

Comment: This ignores the second index and assumes the dictionary is sorted by index, which probably isn't a safe assumption. For example: `{(0, 1): 11,(0, 0): 13}` results in `[[11, 13]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dynamic array (an array which resizes when required) using `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

test_dict = {
 (0, 0): 11,
 (0, 1): 13,
 (0, 2): 33,
 (1, 0): 24,
 (1, 1): 20,
 (1, 2): 4
}

matrix = np.empty((1,1), dtype=int)

# fill the matrix
for (y,x), val in test_dict.items():
    # update matrix shape when required
    if x + 1 > matrix.shape[1]:
        matrix.resize((matrix.shape[0], x + 1))
    if y + 1 > matrix.shape[0]:
        matrix.resize((y + 1, matrix.shape[1]))
    # add matrix value to matrix
    matrix[y,x] = val
    
print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[11 13 33]
 [24 20  4]]
```